# Hosted build on VSO with Azure PS remove-azurermdscconfiguration fails

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines

Is there any way that the hosted build agent images can keep up with the release cycles within MS itself?

I needed specific cmdlets from contained in release 1.2.0. the Azure powershell module is already up to version 1.2.2

What is the current version of the module running on the hosted build agents?

Answer (score 0):

As on March 6 2016, the version of Azure Powershell module on Hosted Agents is **AzurePSCmdletsVersion= 1.0.0**

One hacky alternative I could think of is to add a task in your flow which will install the latest powershell on the hosted agent and then you can use the normal azure powershell task since it will pick up the new version.

You can find the powershell cmdlets to install the latest Azure module from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)

The new hosted image should be rolled out in couple of working days but I am not sure that will have the latest Azure module or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check what version of the Azure cmdlets are installed on a build server in Control Panel for the VSTS account.

In the VSTS account go to:
- control panel (settings gear next to your name in the top nav)
- select agent pools tab
- select an agent pool
- select an agent
- then select "Capabilities" next to Requests on the right hand pane.

Comment: But this is the minimum, and we can't modify, which is a shame... Each agent may a different version...

Comment: Each hosted agent will have the same version... you can modify it, as Harshil mentioned by adding a task to install the version you need.  If you have a workflow that is tied to specific versions of tools/binaries that are not SxS your best be is going to be a custom build server.